# returns an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

Is this returning an `IEnumerable` or an `IQueryable`?

```
public IEnumerable<OrderRecord> GetAll()
{
    return _repository.Table.Where(x => x.ClientAccount.Id == _userSession.GetCurrentClientAccount()).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Then, using breakpoint @ the `IEnumerable`, doesn't it return an `IEnumerable`? 
Why does it say `Queryable` in the `NHibernate.Linq.NhQuerable` (first line of the debug)?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It returns something, that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. That fact that at the same time that thing implements `IQueryable<T>` doesn't matter.

The same applies to e.g. following situation:

```
public ICollection<string> GetCollection()
{
    return new List<string>();
}
```

if you try to check what is returned from `GetCollection` you'll get actual class name, `List<string>` in that example. But because method signature states that it returns `ICollection<T>` you'll get only access to methods/properties exposed by `ICollection<T>` interface (ofc. unless you explicitly cast it back to `List<string>`).

Answer (score 3):

`NhQueryable<T>` implements both `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

By calling `AsEnumerable()`, you now have access to the `IEnumerable<T>` methods which will, for example, run additional LINQ methods like `Where` and `Select` from an in-memory collection after the original `IQueryable<T>` query has been executed in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It returns an object of type `Nhibernate.Link.NhQueryable<ACCS.StockControl.Models.OrderRecord>`.

That type happens to implement the `IQueryable<ACCS.StockControl.Models.OrderRecord>`, `IEnumerable<ACCS.StockControl.Models.OrderRecord>`, and `IEnumerable` [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx).